# How to reference urls by view path instead of name in Django 1.8?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Is it necessary in Django to name urls for use in the url template tag?

The following url example is given in the documentation:

```
('^client/([0-9]+)/$', 'app_views.client', name='app-views-client')
```

and can be used in a template like this:

```
{% url 'app-views-client' client.id %}
```

But is there some way to reverse views by path instead of name? There is a way that is deprecated in 1.8 and will be removed in Django 2.0, like this:

```
{% url 'path.to.some_view' v1 %}
```

In 1.8 and beyond is there still a way to reverse a view without naming it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be forward compatible, named urls will become necessary.

The [deprecation timeline for version 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-0) states:

> The ability to reverse() URLs using a dotted Python path will be removed.

Internally, the url tag uses reverse, so it will be subject to the same deprecation.  This is mentioned at the end of the [docs for the url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

If you want to reverse by path still, you could look at [the source for how it's done now](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.5/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L478) and replicate that manually.  But there's probably a good reason behind the decision to remove this ability.